# AngularJS: How to use ng-repeat on a data collection that is hierarchical

Tags: for-loop, angularjs, hierarchy, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am receiving a collection from server that is hierarchical. ie., I've a list of Study that contains Series. For example I get below object from server.

```
var studies = [ {studyDescription: 'Study1', series:[ 
                                                {seriesDescription:'Series1'}, 
                                                {seriesDescription:'Series2'}
                                              ]
                }];
```

'series' is nested within a study.

I am using a HTML table to display this data. And I wanted to flatten the hierarchy while displaying. ie the table should look like:

```
 Study         Series
 --------------------
 Study1        Series1
 Study1        Series2  ---> Study1 repeats for each series it contains
```

I use ng-repeat to iterate the the rows:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="study in studies">
      <td>{{studyDescription}}</td>
      // HOW to repeat for each series ????
 </tr>
```

How to display such hierarchical data using AngularJS ng-repeat directive? I tried using  before , but that did not work. Basically I need multiple for loops to repeat the rows that many time. How to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: you could include another repeat within top repeat ng-repeat="data in study.series" and then use the value {{data.seriesDescription}}

Comment: I tried by adding a div on top of tr and used ng-repeat. But that did not work. So I tried like this <div ng-repeat="study in studies><tr ng-repeat="series in study.series"><td>{{study.studyDescription}}</td><td>{{series.seriesDescription}}</td></tr></div>. This did not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple `tbody` to iterate on the series :

HTML :

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <th>Studies</th>
        <th>Series</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="study in studies">
        <tr ng-repeat="series in study.series">
            <td>{{study.studyDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{series.seriesDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/L3MWJ/1/

Tell me if it works for you, still I'm not sure if it will work on all browsers.

Comment: this works, thanks. I tried in Chrome & IE9 (which are the targets, anyway for me). So going with this for now. One difference I see between browsers the sort order (of studies) was different, but that I can manage by applying with filters.

Comment: This approach supports only 2-dimension arrays (because `tbody` and `tr` can not be nested inside each other). Can you suggest anything to multi-dimension herarchies?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try nested ng-repeat ? Try this  :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="study in studies">
      <td>{{study.studyDescription}}</td>
     <td> 
         <span ng-repeat="serie in study.series"></span>
               <p>  {{serie.seriesDescription}}</p>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: hi vpoulain, this did not work. The <tr> itself should repeat, right? In your proposal that would not happen, anyways.